# docker php5.6-apache: how to execute commands AFTER mounting but leave apache running

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am building an image starting from php5.6-apache

I need to mount app directory

And *after* mounting dirs, I need to run some command

The problem is that if I add 'command' to docker-compose, the image default entry point is no more executed

How can I

- mount dirs
- run commands (multiple !)
- execute apache image default entry points

Comment: Can you give an example of what the setup steps and mounted content are?  From the description, it sounds like your image might be incomplete, and you're trying to provide the actual application via a bind mount; can you `COPY` the app code into the image (and not mount it), and `RUN` the setup commands, all in the Dockerfile?

Comment: I cannot copy app, I need to mount it because it's for development purpose. So I want app to be mounted on the running container to be served by internal apache, but I need to run composer install, npm install, gulp, and migrations, and so on when volumes are ALREADY mounted. Anyway the accepted answer is working, I didn't know I can create a custom entrypoint which can launch the original one equivalent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  php:
    image: php:5.6-apache
```

When you do `docker-compose up` you should see output like this:

```
Starting 78107088_php_1 ... done
Attaching to 78107088_php_1
php_1  | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.16.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
php_1  | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.16.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
php_1  | [Wed Mar 06 05:07:54.212028 2024] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) PHP/5.6.40 configured -- resuming normal operations
php_1  | [Wed Mar 06 05:07:54.212069 2024] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
```

To do what you propose you need to create a script, `custom-entrypoint.sh` (you can choose another name as long as you use it consistently).

```
#!/bin/bash

# Your custom commands go here.
echo "* Hello, World!"

echo "* Content of mounted volume:"
ls /mnt

# Run original entrypoint.
exec docker-php-entrypoint apache2-foreground
```

Make it executable with `chmod +x custom-entrypoint.sh`.

Now update your `docker-compose.yml`.

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  php:
    image: php:5.6-apache
    volumes:
      - ./custom-entrypoint.sh:/usr/local/bin/custom-entrypoint.sh
      - .:/mnt
    command: /bin/bash -c "/usr/local/bin/custom-entrypoint.sh"
```

I'm not sure what volumes you are mounting nor what commands you need to run. To simulate I'm mounting the current folder (`.`) on `/mnt`. Also mounting the custom entrypoint script. When you do `docker-compose up` you should not see something like this:

```
Starting 78107088_php_1 ... done
Attaching to 78107088_php_1
php_1  | * Hello, World!
php_1  | * Content of mounted volume:
php_1  | custom-entrypoint.sh
php_1  | docker-compose.yml
php_1  | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.16.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
php_1  | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.16.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
php_1  | [Wed Mar 06 05:12:44.372815 2024] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) PHP/5.6.40 configured -- resuming normal operations
php_1  | [Wed Mar 06 05:12:44.372844 2024] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
```

You can see that the extra commands are run: (1) print "Hello, World!" and (2) list the mounted volume. It then proceeds with the default entrypoint as before.

Comment: thanks. It works. I inspected the original php5.6-apache image to try to understand how to use entrypoint and cmd in my img without avoid to launch the original one. Thanks